# Generic Entity Framework mapping

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection, lambda

To beginning I'm novice with Expression and Func.

I'm trying to avoid duplicate code in my EF mapping class, and I'm stuck with bad database.

Take the following example map class:

```
public class EntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        Property(x => x.PropertyA.Property);
        Property(x => x.PropertyB.Property);
    }
}
```

Where `PropertyA` and `PropertyB` are same type, and with many property
Is it possible to refactor this with a simple method, pass `x => x.PropertyA` or `PropertyB` in parameters and do something like `Property(x => x. methodParemeter Property);` ? And how ?
The method could be something like that:

```
private void SubMap(Expression<Func<Entity, SubEntity>> propertyExpression, string prefix)
{
    Property(x => x.propertyExpression.Property)
            .HasColumnName(string.Format("{0}{1}", prefix,"columnName"));
}
```

Comment: In what way would that be an improvement?

Comment: I dont understand the question do you want to map classA propertiesto class B automaticaly

Comment: So instead `.Property` you mean, for example, `.MaxLength(50)`, and you wish to call that with a denser syntax on multiple properties? So you want something like `{ f => f.PropertyA, f => f.PropertyB}.ForEach(p => p.MaxLength(50))`?

Comment: My advice.... Ditch EF and get Dapper  https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Comment: @nurdyguy, I can't, and EF is not my first choice too.

Comment: Ever time I have run into this I have ended up having to tear down the db and build it back up completely.  I have had terrible luck with the mapping and refactory.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could do with with a base class and an interface.

**Models**

```
public interface IEntity
{
    string PropertyA { get; set; }
    string PropertyB { get; set; }
}

public class EntityA : IEntity {
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB : IEntity
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

**Base class**

```
public abstract class IEntityMap<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    protected IEntityMap()
    {
        this.Property(x => x.PropertyA);
        this.Property(x => x.PropertyB);
    }
}
```

**Mapper Implementations**

Register these with your `DbContext` type.

```
public class EntityAMap : IEntityMap<EntityA>
{
    public EntityAMap() : base()
    {
    }
}

public class EntityBMap : IEntityMap<EntityB>
{
    public EntityBMap() : base()
    {
    }
}
```